# How to share ManagedBean with SessionScoped across GAE modules

Tags: google-app-engine, module, gae-module

I'm using GAE (version 1.9.14) with modules (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)

I believe each modules will have it own session.  Anyone know how can I share the ManagedBean with SessionScoped across GAE modules (i.e cross domain)

i.e. User authenticated from moduleA and userSession object is set.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userSession")
@SessionScoped
public class UserSession...
```

when user switch to moduleB, moduleB should be able retrieved the userSession object set by moduleA.

p/s: I notice when browse from one module to another, same cooie are set but with diff JESSIONID.

Any help?